# Retrieve data from JSON file by ID in Angular. TypeError: items.find is not a function

Tags: json, angular, nested, find, typeerror

Trying to get data by id from JSON file, but gives the error in console

```
 TypeError: items.find is not a function

{
"product" :{
       "data" : [
           { "itemID" : "1" , "name" : "pen" , "qty" : "8" }`,
           { "itemID" : "2" , "name" : "notepad" , "qty" : "5" } 
  ]

} }
```

Function I am using where TypeError: items.find is not a function in console

```
       getitems(itemID: string) {
           return this.http.get<Array<Fruits>>('assets/localjson.json')
           .pipe(
           map((items: Array<any>) => {
            return items.find((item: Fruits) => {
             return item.itemID=== itemID;

         });
         })
          );
         }
          office.ts
            export class officeitems {
               itemID: string;
               name: string;
               qty: string;

            }
```

Comment: Try `map(res: any) => res.product.data.find((item: Fruits) =>item.itemID=== itemID)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your structure correctly. Your structure is an object and you have treated it as an array.

So, you need to get your data from the product attribute because data is your array.

You need to change your getItems method and fix the interface defined.

```js
   map((product: any) => { // <- you need to use your interface Product { } instead of any 
    return product.data.find((item: Fruits) => {
      return item.itemID=== itemID;
    });
```

```
{
  "product" :{
       "data" : [
           { "itemID" : "1" , "name" : "pen" , "qty" : "8" }`,
           { "itemID" : "2" , "name" : "notepad" , "qty" : "5" } 
    ]
  }
}
```